# How to make link underline effect that transitions from left to the right in Tailwind?

Tags: html, css-animations, css-transitions, tailwind-css

I can make a `growing underline effect` which will grow to full width and then shrink to its origin:

```
<a href="#" class="group font-normal">
    Home
    <span class="block max-w-0 group-hover:max-w-full transition-all h-0.5 bg-slate-200"/>
</a>
```

How do I create a similar effect but with the `underline` exiting to the right like in version 1 of this [demo](https://tympanus.net/Development/LineHoverStyles/)

Comment: You linked to the solution of your question already. With which part do you struggle exactly? All you have to do is add each style one after the other to your element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0lVX81wOJy) I believe you looking for

```html
<a href="#" class="hover:before:scale-x-100 hover:before:origin-left relative before:w-full before:h-1 before:origin-right before:transition-transform before:duration-300 before:scale-x-0 before:bg-red-500 before:absolute before:left-0 before:bottom-0 ">
    Hover me
</a>
```

The trick here is to change CSS `transform-origin` direction on hover

```
before:origin-right hover:before:origin-left
```

Answer (score 0):

use this as your base and add your styles to it

this one goes to left

```
<button class="relative py-1 after:absolute after:bottom-0 after:left-0 after:w-full after:scale-x-0 hover:after:scale-x-100 after:transition-all after:origin-left after:h-[2px] after:bg-black">Hover Me</button>
```

and this one to right

```
<button class="relative py-1 after:absolute after:bottom-0 after:left-0 after:w-full after:scale-x-0 hover:after:scale-x-100 after:transition-all after:origin-right after:h-[2px] after:bg-black">Hover Me</button>
```

chnage `origin-[direction]` to whatever direction you want

Comment: Hey, the effect you've described I already have. The question was how to make a transition line that appears `left`  and disappears `right` (like in the demo I've provided)